# factory_girl singleton dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have an interesting scenario.

I have a **task** model which has a **task status**:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :task_status
end

class TaskStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tasks
end
```

I define factories for both of those models for my testing:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    title  'sample task'
    task_status { |task| task.association(:actvice_status) }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :active_status do
    status_value "ACTIVE"
  end
end
```

The problem comes when creating instances for testing:

```
10.times do
  task = FactoryGirl.create(:task)
end
```

This will create 10 tasks and also 10 "ACTIVE" task statuses.  In reality, I need just 1 task status, which the task can reference.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing:

```
active = create(:active_status)
tasks = []
10.times do
    tasks << create(:task, task_status: active)
end
```